# The product of finer topologies is finer

Tags: general-topology

I have an exercise, which I have gotten the solution for, but I do not see how the solution is correct.  The exercise:

> Let $X$ and $X'$ denote a single set in the topologies $\mathcal{T}$
>   and $\mathcal{T}'$, let $Y$ and $Y'$ denote a single set in the
>   topologies $\mathcal{U}$, and $\mathcal{U}'$. Assume that these sets
>   are nonempty.
>
> Show that if $\mathcal{T}\subset\mathcal{T}'$, and $\mathcal{U}\subset
> \mathcal{U}'$, the product topology on $X'\times Y'$ is finer than the
>   product topology on $X\times Y$.

the answer given is:

> Every basis in the set $X\times Y$ is a basis in the set $X'\times
> Y'$.

But when I try to show this I do not see how, here is my  attempt at the solution:

We have that the topology on $X$ is

$\mathcal{T}_X=\{X\cap U: U \in \mathcal{T}\}$,

the topology on $X'$ is

$\mathcal{T}_{X'}=\{X'\cap U_2: U_2 \in \mathcal{T}'\}$,

the topology on $Y$ is

$\mathcal{T}_Y=\{Y\cap U_3:U_3\in\mathcal{U}\}$

and last, the topology on $Y'$ is

$\mathcal{T}_{Y'}=\{Y'\cap U_4: U_4\in \mathcal{U}'\}$.

By the definition for the product topology, we have that a basis for $X\times Y$ is:

$\mathcal{B}_{X\times Y}=\{l_1\times l_2|l_1 \in \mathcal{T}_X\,l_2 \in \mathcal{T}_Y\}$.

And we have that a basis for the toplogy on $X'\times Y'$ is :

$\mathcal{B}_{X'\times Y'}=\{l_3\times l_4 |l_3 \in \mathcal{T}_{X'}, l_4 \in \mathcal{T}_{Y'}\}$

But now, I do not see that $\mathcal{B}_{X\times Y}\subset \mathcal{B}_{X'\times Y'}$? Because as the exercise is given, we do not know how $X$ and $X'$ are related? We do know that every $U\in \mathcal{T}\subset\mathcal{T}'$, and $U_3\in \mathcal{U}\subset\mathcal{U}'$. But does this solve the problem?

PS: The exercise is in chapter 16 of Munkres Topology, it is exercise number 5 in this Chapter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’ve misunderstood the question. $X$ is not a subset of some bigger set on which a topology $\mathcal{T}$ is defined: the topology on $X$ *is* $\mathcal{T}$. Similarly, the topology on $X'$ is $\mathcal{T}'$, the topology on $Y$ is $\mathcal{U}$, and the topology on $Y'$ is $\mathcal{U}'$.

Moreover, $X=X'$: they are the same set, but the author uses the name $X$ for that set when it’s to be considered with the topology $\mathcal{T}$, and the name $X'$ when it’s to be considered with the topology $\mathcal{T}'$. Similarly, $Y$ and $Y'$ are two names for the same set; the author uses the name $Y$ when he wants to consider it with the topology $\mathcal{U}$, and the name $Y'$ when he wants to consider it with the topology $\mathcal{U}'$.

Comment: Thank you, that made it very clear!

Comment: @user119615: You’re welcome; glad to help!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott But why is it a finer topology? is it like product of two sub spaces  that are surely contained in the product of the 2 spaces they are a part of?